# How to make Neptune Search more lenient

Tags: elasticsearch, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have some entries inside the graph that I am searching (e.g. `hello_world`, `foo_bar_baz`) and I want to be able to search "hello" and get hello_world back.

Currently, I will only get a result if I search the entire string (i.e. searching `hello_world` or `foo_bar_baz`)

This seems to be due to elasticsearch's standard analyzer behaviour but I don't know how to deal with this with Neptune.

```py
with neptune_graph() as g:
  my_query = " OR ".join(
  f"predicates.{field}.value:({query})" for field in ['names', 'spaces']
  )

  search_results = (
  g.withSideEffect(
  "Neptune#fts.endpoint", f"https://{neptuneSearchURL}"
  )
  .withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.queryType", "query_string")
  .withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.sortOrder", "DESC")
  .V()
  .hasLabel("doc")
  .has(
  "*",
  f"Neptune#fts entity_type:table AND ({my_query})",
  )
 )
```

Comment: can you please post your index mapping as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a wild card.

Given:

```java
g.addV('search-test').property('name','Hello_World')

v[0ebedfda-a9bd-e320-041a-6e98da9b1379]
```

Assuming the search integration is all in place, after the search index has been updated, the following will find the vertex:

```java
g.withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.endpoint",
                 "https://vpc-neptune-xxx-abc123.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com").
  withSideEffect('Neptune#fts.queryType', 'query_string').
  V().
  has('name','Neptune#fts hello*').
  elementMap().
  unfold()
```

Which yields

```java
{<T.id: 1>: '0ebedfda-a9bd-e320-041a-6e98da9b1379'}
{<T.label: 4>: 'search-test'}
{'name': 'Hello_World'}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer to my question,  though I realise my question should really have been "how do I change the analyser to suit my use case" rather than how do I change the search parameters to suit my case

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was indeed the analyzer, except I didn't understand how to fix it until now.

When creating the elasticsearch index in the first place, you need to set what settings you want.

The solution was creating index using

```
with neptune_search() as es:
  es.indices.create(index="my_index", body={/*set custom analyser here*/});

  es.index(index="my_index", ... other stuff);

# example of changing the analyser (needs "" around keys and values)
#body={
#  settings:{analysis:{analyzer:{default:{
#    type: custom, 
#    tokenizer:"lowercase"
#  }}}}
#}
```